# Where should close sqlite connection - iOS App

Tags: ios, sqlite

My iOS app is terminating on the line

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
```

Following is the complete function.

```
-(void)clearCarts
{
    sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;
    const char *sql = "DELETE FROM carts";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error:'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error:'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);// terminates here
}
```

What could be the reason and where should I use `sqlite3_close(database)` as `sqlite3_close(database)` is not being used in any function. 
Please suggest, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be because you are not opening your database to execute the query and you should use `sqlite3_close(database)` after executing the statement.

Try with below code

```
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

if (sqlite3_open([yourDatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString  *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM carts"];
    const char *insert_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,insert_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while Clean Database. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually database is being opened in another function as follow:

`-(id)initContent:(NSString *)source {
     self=[super init];
     int ret = sqlite3_open([source  UTF8String], &database);
     
     if(ret != SQLITE_OK )
     {
         sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"error opening database! error = %i", ret);
     }
          
     return self;
 }`

Comment: Any other suggestion please :) I am very new to this all and need to modify one iOS app. App is not terminating all the time on this statement, sometimes it work fine, some times terminate. Not sure why is it so..

Comment: Make sure you properly close your database after open it or use try catch block to handle properly. You can call sqlite3_close(database); in @finally to make sure you close your connection properly. If its help you then accept the answer.